# How can I make Rspec see my services folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding about how RSpec and Rails loads files, more than solving this specific issue.

My rails application has a common structure, with a new folder:

```
my_app/
      /assets
      /controllers
      /...
      /services (new folder)
      /spec
```

In the spec folder I have a test. At this moment, it only tests the creation of a new instance of my class

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe MyClass do
    context 'something' do
        it 'does something' do
            instance = MyClass.new
        end
    end
end
```

MyClass is a bit special, because in it's constructor a dependency from other of my classes is injected:

```
class MyClass
     def initialize(dependency = MyDependency.new)
         @dependency = dependency
     end
end
```

And to make it a bit more complicated, MyDependency belongs to a group of common classes, that inherits from a base class:

```
require 'my_base'
class MyDependency < MyBase
end
```

This code fails with the following exception:

```
Failure/Error: instance = MyClass.new
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass
```

My test is in the same folder than spec_helper.rb. This helper starts with:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
```

I don't understand what is the mechanism that allows RSpec to access the rails files, and also my services folder. It should consider, MyClass, MyBase and finally MyDependency.

Comment: do you require the `rails_helper.rb` in your specs?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have corrected the spec :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec relies on Rails and Ruby autoloading and Rails and Ruby autoloading is explained in http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/. Autoloading may be unrelated to the error you showed above, however. To understand what's happening there, you should look at and (if you're interested in help) share the backtrace and associated code (e.g. what is calling `.value`).

Comment: You were absolutely right, the error wasn't related at all. Not understanding autoloading well lead me to think that, so the article that you provided was very useful. Thanks a lot!